# Getting Entity data from Autocad

Tags: csv, autocad, dxf

This is a two part question.

1) Is there any way to get a csv file of all the entity data, including xdata, for an autocad dwg, either using autocad or some other method?

2) Is there an easy way to parse a autocad dxf file to get the entity data into a csv file?

Comment: Make sure to 'accept' an answer if it is helpful or solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither approach provides an easy method, but it is possible with a little effort.

With a DWG file, the file itself is binary so your best bet would be to write a plugin or script to AutoCAD, using .NET or ObjectArx, but this may be a troublesome approach. AutoLISP would be easier, but I don't think you could output to a file.

Getting the enitity data out of a DXF would be significantly easier, since the DXF is primarily a text format.  This would be possible with any programming language, but since there are many possible entities it would take some effort to handle all of the cases. The DXF reference is available at the [AutoDESK website](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/item?linkID=10809853&id=12272454&siteID=123112).  XData is certainly also included in the DXF in a text format, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write output to a file using autolisp, even binary output with some slight of hand. However, writing dxf data to a csv file, with or without xdata, by either reading the data directly (in-situ) or by parsing a dxf file, is completely impractical, given the nature of dxf group codes and associated data. Perhaps the OP can identify what he wants to achieve, rather than specifying what appears to me to be an inappropriate format for the data.

Michael.